# Validation in Firebase Rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I got a JSON data structure like this:

```
recipes
   LZogi4JdMk_V5vLK_aA
       title: 'firste recipe'
   LZoh4QphqHknuvda0-f
       title 'secound recipe'
```

I want to make a rule (validation) for the title in each recipe. I have tried doing this:

```
"rules": {
  "recipes": {
    ".write": "auth != null",
    ".read": "auth != null", 
   "$title": {
        ".validate": "newData.isString() 
             && newData.val().length > 0
             && newData.val().length <= 20"
  }
}
```

I think I have to get into each object in the array recipe but i'm not sure. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to firebase docs and samples `$` is used to represent ids and dynamic child keys, currently you are treating `$title` as if it was the ID of each recipe, so your rules should instead look something like this:

```
"rules": {
  "recipes": {
    ".write": "auth != null",
    ".read": "auth != null",
    "$recipeId": {    //example: LZogi4JdMk_V5vLK_aA
      "title": {
        ".validate": "newData.isString() 
             && newData.val().length > 0
             && newData.val().length <= 20"
      }
    }
  }
```

Here's the link to firebase docs:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#structuring_your_rules

Comment: Thanks for you answear I justed named it $recipe and it worked :-)